# When to Unregister LocalBroadcastManager Receiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Can someone give me an example of how to properly unregister **`LocalBroadcastManager` receiver** in `Activity` class?

Android Developers Training suggests do that:

```
 @Override
    public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first

    // When I should to unregister LocalBroadcastManager Receiver before or after super.onPause()?
}
```

and

```
 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        // If the DownloadStateReceiver still exists, unregister it and set it to null
        if (mDownloadStateReceiver != null) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver);
            mDownloadStateReceiver = null;
        }

        ...

        // Must always call the super method at the end.
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

I saw Google's examples but I don't understand when I should to unregister **`LocalBroadcastManager` receiver** before `super.onPause();` or after and in `onDestroy` method before `super.onDestroy();` or after?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATED:**
I register **`LocalBroadcastManager` receiver** in `onResume()` method!

Answer (score 2):

As official doc says (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

> If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead). Do not unregister in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(), because this won't be called if the user moves back in the history stack.

Also, you won't worry about registering/unregistering if your receiver declared statically in your Manifest

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you register it. Basically if you register in i.e. `onResume()` then you unregister in `onPause()`. If you register in `onCreate()` then unregister in `onDestroy()`. I'd suggest to use `onResume()/onPause()` unless you know you need it other way,

And for calling super's methods. in "creation" methods `onCreate` you call super's method **first**. In "desctruction" methids like `onDestroy` you call super's as last thing.

Comment: I register it in onResume() but the question is when I should unregister before `super.onDestroy();`, `super.onPause();` or after superclass' methods?

Comment: I'd unregister in `onPause()` **before** `super.onPause()`

Comment: But why google's training says that you should **Always call the superclass method first**

Comment: It doesn't really matter if you call super.onPause() first or last.

Comment: in `onPause()` it doesn't in `onDestroy()` it might, so it's better to stick to one pattern